# How to do pattern match in haskell options.applicative for record type?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I use `Options.Applicative` to handle haskell command line, my record type for option is like:

```
data Options = Options {  xml :: String
                          ,eut :: String
                       } deriving (Show)

options :: Parser Options
options = Options
              <$> strOption ( short 'x'
                              <> long "xml"
                              <> metavar "XMLFILE"
                              <> value []
                              <> help "GCCXML file for parsing" )
              <*> strOption ( short 'e'
                              <> long "eut"
                              <> metavar "PATH_2_EUT"
                              <> value []
                              <> help "EUT Json filepath for parsing" )
```

Then in my haskell main code, I have:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  options <- execParser parseOpts
  case options of
    Options {xml = [], eut = []} -> putStrLn "use -h to print usage info"
    -- xml option
    Options {xml = _, eut = []} -> parseXML $ xml options
    -- eut option
    Options {xml = [], eut = _} -> genMeta $ eut options
    -- no matching
    _ -> putStrLn "use -h to print usage info"
  where
    parseOpts = info (helper <*> options)
      ( fullDesc
        <> progDesc "Given GCCXML file, generate EUT json and test meta files"
        <> header "map2meta - Generate test meta files" )
```

My intention is to do processing either for `"-x"` or `"-e"`. I achieve this by using pattern `Options {xml = _, eut = []}` to match the case that command line has `"-x"` but no `"-e"`, whereas `Options {xml = [], eut = _ }` to match the case that command line has `"-e"` but no `"-x"`. However, when I run the program without any options, it seems `Options {xml = _ , eut = [] }` get matched. So I added `Options {xml = [], eut = []}` to intercept that case. I think the placeholder '_' actually can be used to match a '[]', though I hoped it would only match to 'something' instead of an empty string. Hence, my first question is how to create a pattern to match a non-empty string?

My second question is how to add code to print out the usage info? Right now, it only print it when I use `"-h"`. I want to print it when there is no options provided in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Since `String` is just a type synonym for `[Char]`, you can match on non-empty strings with the pattern `_:_`, i.e. a non-empty list with a head element `_` (whatever) and a tail list `_` (whatever).

So you could have three cases:

- `Options {xml = _:_, eut = []}`: `xml` is set, `eut` is unset
- `Options {xml = [], eut = _:_}`: `eut` is set, `xml` is unset
- `_`: All the rest (either neither is set, or both are)

Alternatively, you could go with a [multi-way `if`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if):

```
Options{..} <- execParser ...
if | not (null xml) && null eot -> ...
   | not (null eot) && null xml -> ...
   | otherwise -> error ...
```